# Need some guidance in database design

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I work for a 3D printer company and am in the process of designing a mobile app with a SQL Server database backend for the purpose of tracking spools of filament, hot-ends/nozzles (called hozzles), and eventually individual print jobs.

Here's my [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9n6uA.png) for how I think the database should look.

Spools and Hozzles each have their own unique places they can be moved into except for printers which can hold both. All spools will be kept in the database, but when one is "finished" I want to remove it's entire history. All hozzles as well as their histories will be kept in perpetuity.

Are my tables for the spool and hozzle histories appropriate for what I am trying to accomplish?

Would it be better for me to handle attributes like 'spool_size_ID' or 'hozzle_move_ID' with an enum in the API instead of tables in the database?

Any other notes or questions about my approach would be helpful.

Comment: This is not a UML model.

Comment: I've edited the question and dropped the "UML" tag. What is your specific question? A general question like "is my design okay?" is not acceptable for SO.

Comment: Before saying anything i would like to know that wht is hozzle_id and hozzele_id2 ?can there be hozzle_id3 and so on ?Also what if hozzle_id 1 fail more than once so will there be as many rows.Same Hozzle can fail more than once so will there be repeated data in Hozzle table.Thanks.

Comment: @KumarHarsh There are no plans in the foreseeable future to support print jobs with more than 2 hozzles. hozzle_2_id and spool_2_id are intended to be optional, however, I can see how it would make sense to handle the hozzles with another table if the amount was arbitrary.  As for hozzle failures, if a hozzle fails it enters a similar state as a finished spool and is no longer available for use.